# Looking for Scala Play openapi(swagger) generator integrated to sbt build

Tags: scala, playframework, swagger, openapi-generator

I want to configure openAPI(swagger) spec as golden source for Scala Play Server.

Akka play + sbt supports out of the box "conf/routes" file. Sbt generates code base on "routes" file on build stage. Functionality of "routes" file is not enough for me. Because I want to contract complex object types and be able to generate clients on various languages.

I found that https://openapi-generator.tech/ is able to generate Akka play project based on swagger contract.It generates objects from swagger "/components/schemas/..." and "routes" for sbt, actually. It has no integration with SBT, so it will be hard update API code after swagger contract update.

Other tool  https://guardrail.dev/ has sbt plugin https://github.com/guardrail-dev/sbt-guardrail. This plugin generate the API code, but you have to manually binds routes to the server.

Do you know more scala libs for openapi(swagger) codegen?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to search for a `lib` or `plugin` that has some `integration with play and swagger`, you will find some repos that are not pretty active or they are archived like the followings:

- [swagger-api - swagger-play](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-play) (archived)
- [kinoplan - swagger-play](https://github.com/kinoplan/swagger-play): last ocmmit on Aug 9, 2022
- [iheartradio - play-swagger](https://github.com/iheartradio/play-swagger) last commit on Apr 10, 2023 (looks active yet)

The problem I see with them, like you mentioned in your question, is that you have to do some stuff manually. If you generate the code, then you have to bind the routes and endpoint handlers. If you add annotations to the classes and methods, then you manually need to update them if you change something.

I would suggest to consider [tapir](https://tapir.softwaremill.com/en/latest/). It lets you write scala code that can generate `Open API` spec docs and also has integrations to generate `http clients` and `http servers` for different frameworks such as `akka-http`, `play`, `http4s` and many other popular ones. With this library, you can define the specification of the endpoints using scala code that can be compiled letting you find errors at that stage and also makes easier to split the business logic of your app from the contract definition for your endpoints.

In the case of play, it will force you to stop using the `conf/routes` file, but it should not be a big deal. The official doc is great and gives detail about how you can create a [play server using tapir](https://tapir.softwaremill.com/en/latest/server/play.html). So, the migration must be straightforward.

This is how you define a basic endpoint in `tapir`

```
case class ToDo(...)

val rootEndpoint = endpoint.in("api")

val toDoBase = rootEndpoint.in("todo")

val allToDos = toDoBase
  .description("return all the todos")
  .out(jsonBody[List[ToDo]])

val getOneToDo = toDoBase
  .post
  .in(path[UUID]("id")).description("the id of the todo")
  .description("return just one todo")
  .out(jsonBody[ToDo])

val deleteToDo = toDoBase
  .delete
  .in(path[UUID]("id")).description("the id of the todo")
  .description("delete one todo")
```

From here, you can generate the Open API Spec, create a client and a server. Also client and server can use different http libs or frameworks.